# Django Generic Create and Update View

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django so any help would be appreciated.
Here's my situation.
I have a model Patient and I have classed based view for create, update, delete, details. They all are working perfectly. Now I have a dashboard where i am displaying patients details in datatable (like name, age, address etc), I also have a button which is supposed to add report for the patient (like lab tests- Urine test, Stool tests) etc. I successfully created create view but I am not being able to create update view. What I am looking for is when user clicks in report button in dashboard, it would be great if i could display create view if the report hasn't been added else display update view. I know in plain programming world, i could do database query and generate url accordingly but I am not sure how it's done in django.
[image]

CreateView is working. I don't how should i write create/update view for the dashboard url.

```
class Patient(models.Model):

invoice_num = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
patient_manual_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, default='M',)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['id']

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('patient_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

@property
def patient_detail_link(self):
    return "<a href='" + reverse("patient_update", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})+"'>Update</a>"

@property
def patient_id_link(self):
    return "<a href='" + reverse("labreport_create", kwargs={"patient_id": self.pk})+"'>Report</a>"

def __str__(self):
    return self.id

class Clia(models.Model):

patient = models.OneToOneField(
    Patient,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True,
)
clia_ft3            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
clia_ft4            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
clia_tsh            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.id

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('labreport_update', kwargs={'patient_id': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class CliaCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
model = Clia
fields = ['clia_ft3', .... 'clia_fsh', 'clia_lh', 'clia_anti_tpo', 'clia_afp', 'clia_b_hcg', 'clia_cea', ]
#success_url = reverse_lazy('labreport_create')
success_message = "Record added successfully"

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=kwargs['patient_id'])
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.patient = self.patient
    return super().form_valid(form)

class CliaUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Clia
    template_name='labreports/clia_form.html'
    fields = ['clia_ft3', ..... 'clia_fsh', 'clia_lh', 'clia_anti_tpo', 'clia_afp', 'clia_b_hcg', 'clia_cea', ]
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('labreport_update')
    success_message = "Record updated successfully"
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('<int:patient_id>', views.CliaCreate.as_view(), name='labreport_create'),
path('<int:patient_id>/update', views.CliaUpdate.as_view(), name='labreport_update'),
```

]

Comment: Can you share your models please?

Comment: Is there any relation between report and patient?

Comment: 'class Patient(models.Model):'
    'invoice_num = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)'
    'patient_manual_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)'


'class Clia(models.Model):'
    'patient = models.OneToOneField('
        'Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)'

Comment: instead of comments, please update the actual question :) .

Comment: Please check my updated answer. hope it helps. thanks

Comment: @ruddra updated the actual questions

Comment: @ruddra I think if I could find a way how to check if record exists in model and generate absolute url accordingly then i might work..

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer:

Add a new method in model:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    ...
    def create_report(self):
        return reverse("labreport_create", kwargs={"patient_id": self.pk})
```

I would recommend something like this:

You can create a separate UpdateView same as create view:

```
class CliaUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Clia
    fields = ['clia_ft3', ...[other fields]..., 'clia_cea', ]
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('labreport_create')
    success_message = "Record updated successfully"
```

Now in dashboard template, you can add the following logic:

```
{% for patient in object_list %} // rendering all patient
    # do rest of stuff for rendering dashboard
    {% if patient.clia %}
        <a href=<a href="{{ patient.clia.get_absolute_url }}">Report</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ patient.create_report }}">Report</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

#### Explanation:

In template, I am checking a patient has any `Clia`, as they have [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation, so I can use `patient.clia` to check it exists.

Comment: I am generating url from model  
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('patient_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

Comment: I am not sure that would be relevant. BTW, I am using: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: my dashboard doesn't have have any django templating codes..just a plain table html and everything is passed through datatable-django-rest-framework...I have to do if/else (to generate create/update url) in models i think...

@property
def patient_id_link(self): (something here)

Comment: TBH, I don't like putting html code in python. I have updated the answer according to your comments, except for the html parts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding slug to View worked

```
slug_field = 'patient_id'
slug_url_kwarg = 'patient_id'
```

I also had to change the url

```
url(r'^create/(?P<patient_id>\d+)', views.CliaCreate.as_view(), name='labreport_create'),
url(r'^update/(?P<patient_id>\d+)', views.CliaUpdate.as_view(), name='labreport_update'),
```